# Is $[0,1) \cup \{2\}$ a manifold with boundary? My issue is the $2$.

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

- This has been asked about here: [Understanding topological and manifold boundaries on the real line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388254/understanding-topological-and-manifold-boundaries-on-the-real-line), and [Sharkos](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/37268/sharkos) said

> Personally I'd say $M$ wasn't a valid manifold with boundary because the $\{2\}$ doesn't have a neighborhood with any structure like an open ball/half-ball.

- This is actually an exercise from An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu and is not mentioned in an [errata](http://sites.psu.edu/ehssan/wp-content/uploads/sites/7257/2013/10/Errata-for-An-Introduction-to-Manifolds-Second-Edition.pdf).

[image]

[image]

- I have spent almost 2 hours thinking about an exercise that looked like it would take only 15 minutes and even tried pasting lemma (it's a good thing Professor Tu has solutions unlike [Professor Lee](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/750821/636532)): The result of all that thinking is that I don't think $[0,1) \cup \{2\}$, $(\varepsilon,1) \cup \{2\}$ or $\{2\}$ is homeomorphic to any open subset of $\mathscr H^1$ or $\mathscr L^1$. I was able to show $\{0\} \subseteq \partial M$ and $(0,1)\subseteq M^0$, but I don't quite know where $2$ belongs. I believe $M$ is not locally $\mathscr H^1$.
- Also, I have double checked: I believe "manifold boundary" was defined for manifolds with boundary, so this isn't some trick where "manifold boundary" is actually defined for a Hausdorff and second countable space that need not be locally $\mathscr H^n$.

---

To generalize,

> Is a half-open interval and a point not in the interval's closure a manifold with boundary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to refer to a definition of *manifold with boundary*.

Tu says

> A topological $n$-manifold with boundary is a second countable, Hausdorff topological space that is locally ${\cal H}^n$.

where ${\cal H}^1 = [0,\infty)$ with the usual topology, and

> We say that a topological space $M$ is *locally* ${\cal H}^n$ if every point $p \in M$ has a neighborhood $U$ homeomorphic to an open subset of ${\cal H}^n$.

Now consider $[0,1) \cup \{2\}$. Because of the line segment, it can only be a manifold with boundary if it is $n=1$ dimensional.

Now consider $p = 2$. Then every neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ contains an open set containing only one point. But no open set in ${\cal H}^1$ contains only one point. Hence $U$ cannot be homeomorphic to any subset of ${\cal H}^1$. Therefore, this is not a manifold with boundary.

---

As far as I can see, this isn't really open for debate given Tu's definitions (though perhaps I'm missing something!).

**Edit**: I should emphasize that it's fairly arbitrary whether one defines only "topological $n$-manifold" and "topological $n$-manifold with boundary", or if one  generalizes to "topological manifold" and "topological manifold with boundary" where the $n$ can vary between different $p \in M$. As far as I can see, Tu does not actually define the latter notions.

If one *does* define these notions, then clearly this is a topological manifold which is a union of an $n=0$ manifold $\{2\}$ and a $n=1$ dimensional manifold with boundary $[0,1)$.

Comment: Does Tu define *topological manifold* or just *topological **n**-manifold*?  I agree that $[0,1) \cup \{2\}$ is not a topological $n$-manifold with boundary for any fixed $n$, but I would definitely call it a topological manifold with boundary.

Comment: I don't know about Tu, but the standard definition is that $M$ is a topological manifold if there exists $n \in \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ such that $M$ is a topological $n$-manifold. So by this definition, $[0,1) \cup \{2\}$ is **not** a topological manifold (with boundary or otherwise). @JasonDeVito

Comment: @Lee:  The standard definition I am used to allows $M$ to have components of different dimensions.  I agree that by your "standard" definition, $[0,1)\cup\{2\}$ is not a manifold with boundary.  But I also think that with my "standard" definitition, it is.

Comment: @JasonDeVito The given definition is the only definition of a manifold with boundary. For what it's worth, the without-boundary definitions technically also restrict to topological $n$-manifold: "A topological space $M$ is locally Euclidean of dimension $n$...", and "A topological manifold is a Hausdorff, second countable, locally Euclidean space. It is said to be of dimension $n$ if it is locally Euclidean of dimension $n$." It's purely a semantic issue though. I'll edit the answer to emphasize this a matter of convention only.

Comment: Thanks Sharkos!

Comment: Sharkos and @JasonDeVito, I guess [Tu has a convention](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273320/can-a-topological-manifold-be-non-connected-and-each-component-with-different-di) that manifolds without boundary do not necessarily have uniform dimensions, but I don't think there is an explicit one for manifolds with boundary. (Actually, I think his convention for submanifolds (of manifolds without boundary) is having uniform dimensions.) Probably there was meant to be a transfer of different dimensions from manifolds without boundary to manifolds with boundary?

Comment: @JasonDeVito What's your reference please for the non-uniform dimensions? Lang? The only [reference Moishe Kohan found was Lang](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3306262/636532).

Answer (score 4):

The subset $[0,1[ \cup \{2\}$ of the real line is a manifold with boundary having two connected components of different dimensions.  The component $[0,1[$ is a 1-dimensional manifold with boundary, and the single point {2} is a 0-dimensional manifold.

Comment: Prof Tu, does the idea in [Eric Wofsey's answer on question for your definition of manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2273365/636532) apply to your definition of manifolds with boundary? I mean, for example you say [that manifolds with boundary have dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmETl.png) at least 1, but what is meant is that manifolds with boundary have dimension at least 1 *if* they have dimensions? Also, I think there's another mistake: You meant manifolds with boundary have dimension at least 1 provided they have dimensions in the first place and have nonempty boundary?

Comment: I asked about the latter [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if)