# Definition topological manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

In the book "An introduction to manifolds" by Tu, a topological manifold is defined to be a topological space $M$ that is Hausdorff, second countable and locally Euclidean.

Does this allow things like the disjoint union of a plane and a line? Then we have a component which is locally Euclidean of dimension $1$ and one of dimension $2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu allows manifolds having connected components of different dimensions. He explicitly says it in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3146131/is-0-1-cup-2-a-manifold-with-boundary-my-issue-is-the-2/3209055#3209055). Usually people talk about a space being "locally $\Bbb R^n$" or "locally Euclidean of dimension $n$" as opposed to just "locally Euclidean", as he does. But it is not hard to show that for each $n \geq 0$, the set $$\{ x \in M \mid x \mbox{ has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to }\Bbb R^n  \}$$is both open and closed in $M$. So this means that the dimension is well defined on each connected component of $M$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Don't you mean "homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$"?

Comment: Also, could you briefly sketch why the set you wrote down is closed? This is not immediately clear to me. I tried taking a sequence $x_n \to x$ where $x_n$ is in the set and show that $x$ is in the set as well.

Comment: @user745578 It is closed because the complement is open :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But why? If you take a point $x$ not in that set, then you know that $x$ has no open neighborhood homeomorphic to some open subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$. Then why is this the case for a nbh of $x$ as well?

Comment: If $x_k\to x$ and each $x_k$ has a neighborhood homemorphic to $\Bbb R^n$, use that $x$ has a neighborhood homeomorphic to some $\Bbb R^m$. This contains one of the $x_k$'s by convergence. The transition between the charts is a homeomorphism between open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$. So $n=m$.

Comment: @IvoTerek Yes, of course! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does. In the remark right after Definition 5.2, Tu states "Of course, if a topological manifold has several connected components, it is possible for each component to have a different dimension." The disjoint union of a plane and a line is a valid example of such a space. Note that the dimension will be constant on each connected component, so nothing more egregious than this example can happen.